# Jquery only one div active on mouseleave/mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm fairly new to Jquery because most of the time I'm working in Django but you gotta do what you gotta do. I've created a navbar with a dropdown and I've written some messy JQ code to "run it" but the problem is that when I hover on one element and I will move my mouse on to other element previous one stays visible or active, they bunch up. Here is JSFiddle with my code so you can understand how my code "works".

https://jsfiddle.net/ze3ms21c/

```js
$('.iconContent1 ').mouseover(function() {
  $('.helpBox1').show();
});

$('.helpBox1').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.helpBox1').hide();
});


$('.iconContent2').mouseover(function() {
  $('.helpBox2').toggle();
});

$('.helpBox3 ').mouseover(function() {
  $('.helpBox3').show();
});

$('.helpBox3').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.helpBox3').hide();
});
```

Comment: Why do you need jquery for this task? This can simply be solved via css, using :hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did change nothing in the HTML and CSS...

Using some [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) is useful here.

```js
$("[class^='iconWrapper']").mouseover(function(e) {
  $("[class^='helpBox']").hide();
  $(this).next("[class^='helpBox']").show();
});

$("[class^='helpBox']").mouseleave(function() {
  $("[class^='helpBox']").hide();
});
```

```css
.grid-container-PC {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 0.5fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "topBar topBar topBar topBar topBar topBar" "navBar navBar navBar navBar navBar navBar";
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.topBar {
  grid-area: topBar;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.navBar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.65fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ". mainBar mainBar mainBar mainBar ." "bottomBar bottomBar bottomBar bottomBar bottomBar bottomBar";
  grid-area: navBar;
}

.mainBar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 0.2fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ". . . ." "logoBox searchBar searchBar cart";
  grid-area: mainBar;
}

.searchBar {
  grid-area: searchBar;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
}

.cart {
  grid-area: cart;
}

.logoBox {
  grid-area: logoBox;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottomBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: bottomBar;
  background: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64) 0px 2px 8px -5px;
}

.grid-container-mobile {
  display: none;
}

.cartWrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.iconWrapper1,
.iconWrapper2,
.iconWrapper3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.iconContent1,
.iconContent2,
.iconContent3 {
  height: 56px;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.tileLink {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}

.iconPic {
  font-size: 28px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.tileLink:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.iconText {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 7px 0 7px;
}

.iconContent1:hover,
.iconContent2:hover,
.iconContent3:hover {
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 0px 0px 2px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 4px 8px 0px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  z-index: 11;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}

.helpBox1,
.helpBox2,
.helpBox3 {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08) 0px 0px 2px 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 4px 8px 0px;
  padding: 8px 0px 15px;
  left: 0px;
}

.helpBox2 {
  left: 33.33%;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.helpBox3 {
  right: 0%;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.tileListHelpTitle {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  font-size: 15px;
}

.listHelpBox {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

.listStyleHelpBox {
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 3.4vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.linkHelpBox {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a.linkHelpBox {
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
}

a:hover.linkHelpBox {
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.listStyleHelpBox:hover {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

.dayBoxHelp,
.hourBoxHelp {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  font-size: 10px;
}

.loginButtonHelpBox .linkLoginHelpBox,
.loginButtonHelpBox .linkCreateHelpBox {
  background: rgb(0, 130, 250);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 130, 250);
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
}

.loginButtonHelpBox .linkCreateHelpBox {
  color: rgb(0, 130, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 130, 250);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.hrLogin {
  margin: 22px 0px 21px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  position: relative;
}

.textHrLogin {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding: 0px 16px;
  width: 130px;
}

.categoryPC {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 9px 0 9px;
}

.categoryPCLink {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid-container-PC">
  <div class="topBar">
    <div class="topBarWrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navBar">
    <div class="mainBar">
      <div class="searchBar">

      </div>
      <div class="cart">
        <div class="cartWrapper">
          <div class="iconWrapper1">
            <div class="iconContent1">
              <a class="tileLink" href="">
                <div class="iconPic">
                  <i class="fas fa-headset"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="iconText">
                  test1
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="helpBox1">
            <div class="tileListHelpTitle"></div>
            <ul class="listHelpBox ">
              <li class="listStyleHelpBox"><a class="linkHelpBox" href="">jhjhj</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tileListHelpTitle"></div>
            <ul class="listHelpBox">
              <li class="listStyleHelpBox"><a class="linkHelpBox" href="">jhjj</a></li>
              <li class="listStyleHelpBox">
                <a class="linkHelpBox" href="">jgjhhjhj</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="dayBoxHelp">
                    Pon. - pt.
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="hourBoxHelp">
                    9:00 - 16:00
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="dayBoxHelp">

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="hourBoxHelp">
                    dgg
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span class="lineHelpBox"></span>
          <div class="iconWrapper2">
            <div class="iconContent2">
              <a class="tileLink" href="{% url 'order'  %} ">
                <div class="iconPic">
                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="iconText">
                  test2
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="helpBox2">
            <div class="tileListHelpTitle">kjk</div>
            <div class="loginButtonHelpBox">

              <div class="helloMsgLogin"> kjkj</div>

              <a href="{% url 'login'  %}">
                <div class="linkLoginHelpBox">

                </div>
              </a>
              <hr class="hrLogin">
              <p class="textHrLogin">kukjk</p>
              <a href="{% url 'register'  %}">
                <div class="linkCreateHelpBox">

                </div>
              </a>

            </div>

            <ul class="listHelpBox ">
              <li class="listStyleHelpBox"><a class="linkHelpBox" href="{% url 'order'  %}">hjjhj</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="iconWrapper3">
            <div class="iconContent3">
              <a class="tileLink" href="">
                <div class="iconPic">
                  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="iconText">
                  test3
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="helpBox3">
            <div class="tileListHelpTitle">
              text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="logoBox">
        <div class="logoWrapper">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love short and compact code and you delivered. Thank you

Comment: @MarcelCzuryszkiewicz, this code can be made even shorter using $(selector).hover...

Comment: Yes. `.hover(func_formouseenter, func_formouseleave)` is nice... It saves one or two lines. But I would definitely check how you use the classes... Everytime you need to add a number to it, it is an indication something is weird. I would refactor that in the HTML and the related CSS rules. And you may not need the attribute selector then...  Have fun coding!

Comment: In short, that answer is a "patch" to some weird HTML/CSS more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of mouseenter and mouse leave instead

EDIT

```
$('.iconContent1,.helpBox1').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.helpBox1').show();
});

$('.iconContent2,.helpBox2').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.helpBox2').show()
});

$('.iconContent1,.helpBox1').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.helpBox1').hide();
});

$('.iconContent2,.helpBox2').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.helpBox2').hide()
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wco15Ls3/)

Comment: It's okey but when i want to click something on the div that appeard I can't because div already disappeared.

Comment: @MarcelCzuryszkiewicz check again please